# replace vowel with another vowel

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to replace the vowel of a word with another vowel. Using list comprehension, my code is only replacing the vowels in the word with block replace with `"aeiou"`, how should I do to make the result look like, 
for example, `'hom'` will be `['ham', 'hem', 'him', 'hum']`?

Thanks in advance!

```
word = "hom"
vowels = "aeiou"
words = [''.join([i if i not in vowels else 'aeiou' for i in word])]
print(words)
```

Comment: What if `word` has more than one vowel in it? What if it has no vowels?

Answer (score 0):

code below replace a vowel randomly with another vowel. sometimes it may replace it with same vowel

```py
import random
"".join([random.choice(vowels) if c in vowels else c  for c in word])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import random
word = "hom"
vowels_lst = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] in vowels_lst:
        rand_let = random.choice(vowels_lst)
        new_word = word.replace(word[i], rand_let)
print(new_word)
```